# UICollectionView - Horizontal paging with 3 pages visible and 1 in the middle using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling, scroll-paging

I'm trying to implement same feature like mobile Safari has when scrolling among different pages using UICollectionView. One page is in the middle and parts of other are also visible.

[image]

I am struggling to achieve such a behaviour using UICollectionView. There is 1 way I found how to put 3 pages at one screen - make pages smaller and set appropriate insets. But as soon as I set pages smaller and I set paging enabled, pages are not scrolled to the centre as they should. I can also leave paging disabled and use this method in subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
- (CGRect)rectForTargetPageForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
```

In this method I can set exactly where UICollectionView will stop. However, scrolling experience is not as good as it was as using UIScrollview with paging enabled. When I swiped with bigger velocity, several pages were scrolled and it stopped on proposed page. What I want to achieve is same behaviour as normal scroll view with paging enabled - whatever velocity I use, I will get only 1 page more.

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this using UICollectionView?

Comment: Why you couldn't just ignore the `velocity` parameter in that method and return the rect for the next page?

Comment: I tried that and scrolling seems strange to me. Its not as good as paging enabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16070570

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make size of a page smaller than the size scroll view, right? Page size is **always** the same as the size of scroll view, so you have to *make the scroll view smaller*.

Then there is another problem. **How to receive touches *out of the bounds* of the scroll view?**

Override `-[UIView pointInside:withEvent:]` of the scroll view to check for larger bounds than they really are. Then the touches should work.

---

In fact I didn't try this myself, I was doing it by placing supplementary view above with desired bounds and override `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`. Inside I modified the point and called scroll view hit test. This way the touches were handled by scroll view, but their position was wrong. You may want to try combining these two approaches to get correct position.

Comment: I dont have problem with that, I just need to have 3 pages in one scrollview and paging enabled. But problem is that paging fits only if there is one page with same frame size that whole collection view. If I create pages smaller, so that I can see other 2 pages, paging is not working correctly. And when I set clipsToBounds to NO, pages that are out of bounds are immediately removed from view hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think you can do something with that. You can achieve it using only scroll view and insert pages manually.

Comment: I found solution. I have to set paging enabled, set clips to bounds to  NO and then overlap items. In flow layout subclass I have to return non overlapping content size, so that cells are not remove from view hierarchy they are scrolled out of bounds. Will have to tune it little bit but it could work.